# Deprecated in 3.0.0. Use SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate() instead

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, ibm-cloud, cloud-pak-for-data

I use PySpark in jupyer using IBM Cloud Pak. I got the warninig: context.py:79: FutureWarning: Deprecated in 3.0.0. Use SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate() instead.

My script:

## PySpark Machine Learning Library

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, Tokenizer
from pyspark.sql import Row, SQLContext

import os
import sys
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *

from pyspark.mllib.classification import LogisticRegressionWithSGD
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from numpy import array

from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
# Library for confusion matrix, precision, test error
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import MulticlassMetrics
# Library For Area under ROC curve and Area under precision-recall curve
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import BinaryClassificationMetrics

# Assign resources to the application
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

# packages for data analysis
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

Comment: `sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)` is deprecated. Use `spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()` instead.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Deprecated means that a function still works in the current version but will be removed in the future

Comment: Oli, where do I use
spark =  SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()